# index page appear as white screen after app deployment for reactjs deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app

I have reactjs app and i made the deployment and upload build folder's content to my server :

mydomain.com/cpanel/

But when i request mydomain.com/cpanel/index.html

the page stay white screen and nothing displayed, i have checked console and i saw the following error:

[GET https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.js](https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.js)

 `net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

also i have requested the above link directly from browser and i got :

Cannot find "/umd/react.production.js" in react@16.12.0

I don't know if the problem in this link or not

Thanks

Comment: You can go to https://unpkg.com/browse/react@16.12.0/umd to see which versions are available. I think the one you're after is https://unpkg.com/browse/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js

Comment: Ok, the 404 not found is cleared
but still the page apear as white screen
this is my hosting:
http://isk-group.net/cpanel/index.html

Comment: Is this what you get on your console: `Refused to execute script from 'https://unpkg.com/browse/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Sorry. My wrong. Try `https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js` (remove `/browse`)

Comment: I can't know what is the problem of this?
This is my first reactjs app uploaded to real server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204753/discussion-between-izhaki-and-fadi-ramzi).